# C: Dynamic memory allocation using pointer to array with fixed number of chars

Tags: c, pointers, portability, dynamic-memory-allocation, bmp

so I guess this is more a stylistic question.

I need to write into a dynamic array of elements with the size of 3 bytes. (bitmap with pixel size of 24bpp)

So, every element would have to be a char[3].
If I want to avoid using a `struct pixel{ char R, char G, char B}`, to avoid the usage of preprocessor statements, is it possible to write it as

```
char* pixel[3]
```

and allocate in steps of `3*sizeof(char)`?

To account for height and width, I would need a char** pixel[3], and having to allocate in single char steps would make that a char*** pixel.

So I guess I'm looking for a way to avoid using a pointer-pointer-pointer.
Thanks!

Comment: Just keep a `char **pixeels` and multiply by 3 each time you want to reallocate.

Comment: usage of `preprocessor statements` ?

Comment: @saadtaame: having an array of lines, to account for width and height, I would already have a pointer-pointer, adding the necessity to allways allocate 3sizeof(char) for every pixel greatly diminishes the readability and simplicity of the code. It's supposed to be easily understandable for my colleagues.

Arashium: writing a struct to file needs either #pragma or _attribute_'s, which are specific to the gcc and won't compile on different platforms.

Comment: You know `sizeof(char)` is always 1?

Comment: I do, yes. It's just that I'm working on an assignment and the coding standard requirements that I was handed specify that I need to write it like this, so I got used to it by now. I hope it's not too inconvenient to read.

Answer (score 3):

Do you mean `N` blocks of 3 `unsigned char`' s [0...255]?

Note the difference:

`unsigned char *pixel[3]`  -> array of pointers to char

Vs

`unsigned char (*pixel)[3]` -> pointer to array of chars

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define N 4

int main(void)
{
    unsigned char (*pixel)[3];

    pixel = malloc(sizeof(*pixel) * N);
    pixel[0][0] = 0;
    pixel[0][1] = 128;
    pixel[0][2] = 255;
    /* ... */
    pixel[3][0] = 0;
    pixel[3][1] = 128;
    pixel[3][2] = 255;

    printf("R:%d G:%d B:%d\n", pixel[0][0], pixel[0][1], pixel[0][2]);
    free(pixel);
    return 0;
}
```

If you don't know `N` before hand replace `malloc` with `realloc`

Answer (score 1):

You can simulate this using a 1D array. Say you want to allocate a `wxh` rectangle of pixels. You could write.

```
char *pixels = (char *) malloc(w*h*3*sizeof(char));
```

Now the 3 color bytes appear contiguous in memory and you can access any cell using some arithmetic

You can get/set the color channels at cell `(i,j)` by defining the macros:

```
#define r(p, i, j) ((p)[(3*((w)*(i)+(j)))])
#define g(p, i, j) ((p)[(3*((w)*(i)+(j)) + 1)])
#define b(p, i, j) ((p)[(3*((w)*(i)+(j)) + 2)])
```

Call looks like `r(pixels, 0, 1)`.

Comment: 1. your cast should be `(char*)`, not `(char**)` and 2. you can't access a `char*` with the convenient `pixels[x][y][channel]` syntax.

Comment: Fixed, thank you! That's true but you can write one line functions (or macros) to do that easily.

Comment: @UniversE You cannot use the "convenient syntax" at all, because compler doesn't know the 3D array dimensions.

Comment: @saadtaame Note that casting result of malloc is unnecessary in C. Also `sizeof(char)` is always `1` by definition, so it is also unnecessary.

Comment: @saadtaame maybe you can add to this answer, how to access a specific element by using x, y and the channel-index. Then I would consider this the best answer for heap memory.

Answer (score -2):

<s>If you don't want structs, you can't avoid writing `char***`.</s>

But you can use a type, to make it more *stylish*.

So the best solution matching your requirements seems to be:

```
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef char*** pixelmap_t;

int main() {

  int channels = 3, width = 10, height = 10;

  pixelmap_t test = malloc(width*height*channels);

  int x = 1, y = 2, channel = 0;

  test[x][y][channel] = 3;

  free(test);

  return 0;
}
```

It seems, I totally fucked up. I confused the following two things:

1. When you declare a static 3D-Array `pixels[100][100][3]`, then the type is **not** `char***`. It is a one-dimensional array of 300 consecutive items in memory.
2. When you declare a `char***` and assign 300 items in memory, then dereferencing all of the dimensions with the `pixels[x][y][z]` syntax results in derefrencing the first dimension and interpreting the value in memory as pointer and derefrencing this pointer instead of computing the correct offset in a 3D-Array.

That means, I overlooked, that the `array[x][y][z]` accessor syntax has two different semantics. The first I would call the `array ([x][y][z])` semantic for 3D-arrays and the second I would call the `((array[x])[y])[z]` semantics for `char***` (I used the brackets for emphasizing).

This code snipped compiles and works (tested it) - but does **not** use heap memory.
For heap memory I don't know an other solution than those, which have been posted already (`malloc(width*height*channels)` and access with `pixels[c + channels*(y + x*height)]`).

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {

  int channels = 3, width = 10, height = 10;

  char test[width][height][channels];

  char *ptr = (char*) test;
  for (int i = 0 ; i < channels * width * height ; i++) {
    ptr[i] = (char) (i % 255);
  }

  for (int x = 0 ; x < width ; x++) {
    for (int y = 0 ; y < height ; y++) {
        for (int c = 0 ; c < channels ; c++) {
            int d = (int) test[x][y][c];
            printf("%d %d - %d : %d\n", x, y, c, d);
        }
    }
  }

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: You cannot make 3D array into jagged array just by pretending that pointer is `char***`.

Comment: Great and readable solution, thank you! Just one question though, wouldn't I have to allocate the char* inside the char** seperately, for the allocation to work? (to my understanding) it seems that your code allocates 300 times the type of char*** but leaves the char** and char* unallocated. (unless I just confused myself)

Comment: thanks! I salute you for the effort and thank you, but that method will not work for large dimensions, as my dimensions go to INT_MAX * INT_MAX. (I know it's not useful to make dimensions that big, but again, it's the assignment..)
So I guess I will have to settle for char***.